# Pre checks and Post checks of SharePoint Server reboot

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

Is there any good list for Pre checks and Post checks of SharePoint Server reboot from SharePoint administration perspective?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing but I can share you some checks which I normally perform. Mostly, we rebooted either due to issues or updates...so normally no pre check. Here couple of thing to verify

- Make Sure SharePoint Admin And Times Service Is Up And Running.
- Make Sure all apps pools are started,
- If It Web Front End Then browse the Web application to make sure they are working.
- If Search app is on that server then test it, same thing with other services apps.
- Check Event Log For Any Potential Error, Check Application, system and setup logs.
  Also check the health rules from central admin, if it detect anything
- If This Is Distributed cache server then make sure DC is up and running.

Answer (score 1):

I also created some lists for our administrations to test email processing - we've had that break on occasion.

I created a 'TestWorkflowEmail' custom list, and left it with just the title column. I added a SPD workflow to run on create, that sends an email to the creator of the item.

I also had the administrator create an alert on the same list, to test that functionality

I also created another list using the announcement template. I added an incoming email to it, so they could test incoming.

So after an update or a reboot, they can:

1. Test alerts and workflow emails by adding an item to the first list
2. Test incoming emails by emailing the address and verifying the information shows up in the second list.